# Getting files order base on users selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, upload

I'm trying to figure how can I feature the photos sequence that users select through the input file. e.g:

Users selected from a list of photos the sequece 1.png, 3.png, 10.png, 2.png, 4.png, 8.png...
o I found out that it will depend on the (windows, Mac OS...) that the users are using. Is there a way to force it?

```
// JavaScript/jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
  const selectedFiles = [];

  // Handle file input change event
  $("#fileInput").change(function() {
    const fileList = $("#fileInput")[0].files;
    const fileListContainer = $("#fileList");
    fileListContainer.empty();

    // Display selected file names and order
    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
      const fileName = fileList[i].name;

      if (!selectedFiles.some(file => file.name === fileName)) {
        selectedFiles.push({ name: fileName, order: selectedFiles.length + 1 });
      }

      const listItem = $("<li>").text(selectedFiles.find(file => file.name === fileName).order + ". " + fileName);
      fileListContainer.append(listItem);
    }
  });

  // Attach click event to file input to capture file order
  $(".file-upload-container").on("click", function() {
    selectedFiles.length = 0;
    $("#fileInput").val(""); // Reset file input to allow re-selection of the same files
  });

  // Drag-and-drop functionality (optional)
  $(".file-upload-container").on("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("file-upload-over");
  });

  $(".file-upload-container").on("dragleave", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("file-upload-over");
  });

  $(".file-upload-container").on("drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("file-upload-over");

    const droppedFiles = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    $("#fileInput")[0].files = droppedFiles;
    $("#fileInput").change();
  });
});
```

Comment: _"depend on the SO"_ - what's an SO?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to force it, and I can't even tell if the specification actually _requires_ any specific order. For most types of applications, it probably doesn't matter much, I suppose. So if you _need_ this for some reason, then you might either need to find a different way to let the user select the files (i.e., provide a single file upload field for every "position" that you need), or show them a list of the selected files first, and let them rearrange the order via buttons or drag&drop.

Comment: I was thinking about that. Thanks for commenting